# correct application of Tannery's theorem on $(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2})^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I know that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)^n = 1$$ but by applyling [Tannery's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannery%27s_theorem), I am getting the answer as zero. Can somebody, help me find the error in the solution below?

$$S_n = \Bigg(1+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\Bigg)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{n \choose k}\bigg(\frac{1}{n^2}\bigg)^k = \sum_{k=0}^n\bigg(\frac{n}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{n-1}{n}\bigg)\cdots\bigg(\frac{n-k+1}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{n^kk!}\bigg)$$

$$\implies S_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(n) \text{ , where } a_k(n) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{ if } k>n \\
       \bigg(\frac{n}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{n-1}{n}\bigg)\cdots\bigg(\frac{n-k+1}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{n^kk!}\bigg) & \text{ if }k\le n
   \end{cases} $$

clearly, $a_k(n)\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 = b_k \text{  ,} \forall k$

and $|a_k(n)| \le \bigg(\frac{n}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{n-1}{n}\bigg)\cdots\bigg(\frac{n-k+1}{n}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{k!}\bigg)\le \frac{1}{k!},\forall n$

and $\sum \frac{1}{k!} = e< \infty$

$$\implies \text{ by Tannery's theorem } \lim_{n\to\infty} S_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} a_k(n) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k = 0$$

But the correct answer is 1. So, where did I go wrong?

Comment: It should be $\sum_{k=0}^n.$ Starting with $k=1$ means you've already subtracted $1$ from your expression.

Comment: @CalvinKhor we actually need $\forall k \space\space \exists \space\space M_k \space\space s.t. \space\space |a_k(n)| \le M_k ,\forall n$ with $\sum M_k<\infty$

Comment: and i show that in the last 3rd and last 4th line in the post above

Comment: I think that $a_0(n) \to 1$ as $n \to \infty.$

Comment: But now $a_0(n)=1$ for all $n,$ so you get convergence to $1.$

Comment: @abhishek sorry, misread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in the definition of $a_k(n)$, since for $k=0$ we have
$$
a_k(n) = {n \choose 0} \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^0 = 1.
$$
This makes the following statement wrong:
$$
a_k(n) {\to} 0 = b_k, \forall k
$$
since is not true for $k=0$, as for $k=0$ we have $a_0(n) = 1$, $\forall n$.
When you substitute it with
$$
b_k = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } k=0 \\
0 & \text{if } k \geq 1
\end{cases},
$$
you will obtain $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n = \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k = 1$.